# Update variable value

Tags: powershell

I have a variable (output) witch value is another variable (version).

```
$VERSION="10"
$OUTPUT=$VERSION
write-host $OUTPUT
```

If I later on the script update the version variable , the output remains the older value

```
$VERSION="20"
write-host $OUTPUT
```

UPDATE ---------

In my case, I think it's a little more tricky

```
$TODAY=get-date -format "yyyymmd"
$VERSION="10"
$LOGERROR=-join([Ref]$VERSION,"_",$TODAY)
write-host $LOGERROR
write-host $LOGERROR.value
$VERSION="20"
write-host $LOGERROR
write-host $LOGERROR.value
```

It's probably the join that is the problem here because I can get an output with the message System.Management.Automation.PSReference but I can't get the output if I use .value

Comment: See http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/04/27/passing-byref-vs-byval.aspx

Comment: When I use the [Ref] I get this: System.Management.Automation.PSReference

Comment: You need to use `$OUTPUT.Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm copying the answer from this site: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/04/27/passing-byref-vs-byval.aspx

Usually, when you assign a variable to another variable, its content is copied. Here is an example:

```
$a = "Hello"
$b = $a
$a = "Hello World"
$b # "Hello"
```

As you can see, $b is actually a copy of $a so when you change $a, $b is not changed. If you want to, you can also just pass a pointer to a variable, effectively having two variables use the very same memory to store its values. To pass a pointer, cast to `[Ref]` like this:

```
$a = "Hello"
$b = [Ref]$a
$a = "Hello World"
$b # "Hello World"
```

This time, changing $a will also affect $b because both are using the same storage. When you look closely at the result, though, you will notice that $b actually is not a string variable anymore. It is now a `PSReference` object, and this object has a value property, giving you the actual object content:

```
$b.Value
```

Likewise, to change the $a variable through $b, you should assign a new value to the value property found in $b:

```
$b.Value = "New Text"
$a # "New Text"
```

Comment: can't I use a -join() with the [Ref]$a ?